# AWS, Route 53, Heroku, works but I don't know Why

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, dns, amazon-route53

I have a website that is a herokuapp app. For the past 5 years I regsitered the domain of this website / app with godaddy, and made the configuration necessary in the DNS and forwarding to the heroku address.

last month I decided to switch over to route 53 and AWS, I filled out the relevant forms and released the domain from godaddy , the transfer succeeded, and the domain is registered with route 53.

I thought that I would have to go in at one point and configure route53 to use the configuration I did in godaddy ( forwarding to heroku ) but somehow without doing anything the domain is working and the forwarding is there.

I have no problem , I just want to know how did this happen? if Route 53 automatically picked up the configuration from godaddy ( which is what I assume happened but would like to know more ) where in route53 can I inspect the configuration ( in casr I want to modify it in the future ).

Thanks.

Update :

After some digging around on www.whatsmydns.net I found out that my site Nameservers are ns44.domaincontrol.com. I called godaddy customer support asking them about this and they said that when they get a request to transfer a domain everything is migrated over (assuming to route53 )
I don;t know when will this expire from ns44.domaincontrol.com, but I still haven;t gone to route 53 and started the process of creating a hosted zone and other details, I am afraid its gonna mess up the existing setup , so If anyone has experience and can recommend a course of action I appreciate it.

Comment: I took a look at AWS's instructions for domain name transferring and didn't see any mention of "automated" configuration: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-transfer-to-route-53.html You might want to visit www.whatsmydns.net and take a look at what name servers are displaying for your records. Since you mention that you did this a month a go that rules out TTL.

Answer (score 1):

When you transfer your domain to AWS Route53 there's an option to keep existing nameservers. You probably chose to do that. But it's not advised as mentioned here in AWS doc:

> If the registrar for your domain is also the DNS service provider for
>   the domain, we highly recommend that you consider transferring your
>   DNS service to Amazon Route 53 or another DNS service provider before
>   you transfer your registration. Some registrars provide free DNS
>   service when you purchase a domain registration. **When you transfer the
>   registration, the previous registrar will not renew your domain
>   registration and could end your DNS service at any time.**

Source: [Transferring Registration for a Domain to Amazon Route 53](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-transfer-to-route-53.html)